# Cannot run program "java" (in directory)

Tags: java, mpj-express

I am trying to integrate MPJ Express in eclipse(Kepler) in Ubuntu 13.04

The environment variables defined in .bashrc are as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/soumya/Work/jdk1.7.0_25
export PATH=$PATH:/home/soumya/Work/jdk1.7.0_25/bin    
export MPJ_HOME=/home/soumya/InstalledSoftwares/mpj-v0_38
export PATH=$PATH:$MPJ_HOME/bin
```

**Problem 1:**
When I start Eclipse I get an error:

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) 
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine 
was found after searching the following locations: 
/home/soumya/Work/eclipse/jre/bin/java java 
in your current PATH
```

This was solved by copying the jre folder inside the Eclipse folder. So now Eclipse starts.

**Problem 2:**
I can't seem to run a multicore program.  In the run configurations of my Java project I have done the following:

- Set a variable `MPJ_HOME` to `/home/soumya/InstalledSoftwares/mpj-v0_38`
- Set environment variable `MPJ_HOME` to `${MPJ_HOME}`
- Set VM Arguments to `-jar ${MPJ_HOME}/lib/starter.jar`

But when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
MPJ Express (0.38) is started in the multicore configuration
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/soumya/Work/EclipseWorkspace/SoftwareArchitectureProject/MulticoreDebuggerDemo"): error=2, No such file or directory

at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
at runtime.starter.MulticoreDaemon.startNewProcess(MulticoreDaemon.java:268)
at runtime.starter.MulticoreDaemon.<init>(MulticoreDaemon.java:109)
at runtime.starter.MPJRun.<init>(MPJRun.java:146)
at runtime.starter.MPJRun.main(MPJRun.java:964)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
... 4 more
```

Comment: This is a very wild guess, but it seems that "java" is not available for MPJ Express. Try typing "java" in a new terminal and see if it is available. If it is, try setting environment variable JAVA_HOME to your actual JDK Home (in Ubuntu e.g. `/usr/lib /jvm/<java-version>`).

Comment: Thanks Jason,

Your comment seemed all that I needed to solve the problem. And yess, the problem was with JAVA. I had downloaded the tar file of Oracle Java, untarred it in home/soumya/Work/ and set the JAVA_HOME and PATH in bashrc according to this path. This was causing the problem.

The proper way of installing ORACLE JAVA in ubuntu linux is provided in http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux.

If installed properly the problem disappears.

Comment: You are welcome, but my name is `zip`not `Jason`, although I would like that name ;)